# How to add files into my binding ListView with Pure XAML

Tags: wpf, binding

So i have `Page` with `Button` and `ListView`.

Via this `Button` the user select files that i want to add into my `ListView`

```
<Page.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelBase x:Key="ViewModelBase"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Button Command="{Binding AddFilesCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModelBase}}"/>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"/>
```

My `ViewModel`:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private ObservableCollection<FileBase> _files;
        public AddFilesCommand AddFilesCommand { get; set; }

        public ViewModelBase()
        {
            _files = new ObservableCollection<FileBase>();
            AddFilesCommand = new AddFilesCommand(this);
        }

        public void AddFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Title = "Please Select File(s)",
                Multiselect = true
            };

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string[] files = openFileDialog.FileNames;
                if (files.Length > 0)
                    AddFile(files);
            }
        }

        public void AddFile(string[] files)
        {
            // Here i am add all my files into my Files collection
        }

        public ObservableCollection<FileBase> Files
        {
            get { return _files; }
            set
            {
                _files= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**AddFilesCommand**

```
public class AddFilesCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public bool canExecute { get; set; }
        public ViewModelBase ViewModel { get; set; }

        public AddFilesCommand(ViewModelBase viewModel)
        {
            canExecute = true;
            ViewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecute;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ViewModel.AddFile();
        }
    }
```

Now this works fine and i can see the all the files that the user select are inside my `Files` collection but i cannot see this files inside my `ListView`

Comment: Your ListView (which should perhaps just be a ListBox) is missing an ItemTemplate with UI element that are bound to the properties of a FileBase item. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Have you assigned the DataContext? I only see the ViewModelBase declared in the Page's Resource. This wouldn't be enough.

Comment: The ViewModelBase instance should not be put in Page.Resources, but in the Page's DataContext. Or you also use `Source={StaticResource ViewModelBase}` on the ItemsSource Binding. It looks odd that you set the Source on one Binding, but not on the other.